# Reference Excel cell in PowerPoint macro for filename

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I can't get SaveAsFixedFormat working from Excel VBA to export a PowerPoint file as PDF. I have resorted to starting a macro in the preset-powerpoint from Excel VBA that exports the presentation as pdf directly from PowerPoint.

Is there any way to reference a cell in the Excel file in this macro that is running in PowerPoint to get the filename?

```
Sub pppdf()

ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat "M:\random\test.pdf", 32

End Sub
```

I can save the PowerPoint file as .pptx from Excel and use varying filenames and paths but now I would like to reference those same paths and filenames in the PowerPoint macro that is exporting to pdf.

In the end I'd like the code to look somewhat like this but this obviously needs some work to function from PowerPoint:

```
Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String

FPath = Range("SavingPath").Value
FName = Sheets("randomworksheet").Range("A1").Text

ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat FPath & FName & " Development" & ".pdf", 32
```

This PowerPoint macro would be started from Excel and both the PowerPoint file and the Excel Workbook and sheet will be open when this is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not open the presentation and save it as a PDF from Excel if the main bulk of the code is in Excel anyway?

```
Sub SavePPTXasPDF()

    Dim PPT As Object
    Dim PP As Object

    Set PPT = CreatePPT
    Set PP = PPT.Presentations.Open("<FullPathToPresentation>")

    PP.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "ABC", 32 'ppSaveAsPDF

End Sub


Public Function CreatePPT(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpPPT As Object

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Powerpoint is not running. '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpPPT = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Powerpoint. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                                 '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    End If

    oTmpPPT.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreatePPT = oTmpPPT

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreatePPT."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

or if you want to run the code in Powerpoint:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oWB As Object
    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String

    Set oXL = CreateXL
    Set oWB = oXL.workbooks.Open("<Path&FileName>")

    'Or if Workbook is already open:
    'Set oWB = oXL.workbooks("<FileName>")

    FPath = oWB.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    FName = oWB.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")

    ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat FPath & FName & " Development" & ".pdf", 32

End Sub

Public Function CreateXL(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpXL As Object

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Excel is not running. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Excel. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                            '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    oTmpXL.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateXL = oTmpXL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateXL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

Or you could, as you requested, open the presentation from within Excel and execute code stored in the presentation:

```
Sub SavePPTXasPDF()

    Dim PPT As Object
    Dim PP As Object

    Set PPT = CreatePPT
    Set PP = PPT.Presentations.Open("<FullPath>")
    PPT.Run PP.Name & "!Test"

End Sub
```

This would use the `Test` macro and use the `Set oWB = oXL.workbooks("<FileName>")` line of code which is currently commented out in my example above.

Comment: Thanks Darren, you've put alot of work into this answer but one of your lines of code actually opened my eyes. I kept trying to use ExportAsFixedFormat from Excel VBA but `PP.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "ABC", 32 'ppSaveAsPDF` this worked great. Just using SaveAs with the pdf numeration. Great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What problem are you facing using ExportAsFixedFormat directly from the Excel VBE? According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746080.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (which seems to be incorrect) and the PowerPoint VBE IntelliSense, the second argument, FixedFormatType can only be one of two values:

```
ExportAsFixedFormat(Path, FixedFormatType, Intent, FrameSlides, _
                    HandoutOrder, OutputType, PrintHiddenSlides, PrintRange, _
                    RangeType, SlideShowName, IncludeDocProperties, KeepIRMSettings)

FixedFormatType:

ppFixedFormatTypePDF = 2
ppFixedFormatTypeXPS = 1
```